# Is Munafiqat is haram in islam/ Leg Pulling in office

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, forgiveness, belief, respect

Assalam o Alaikum!
I'm at my office and there is too much hate ness among all the employees, Everyone Is pulling the leg of each other and make some non sense act like talk to other person that he/she was like this this and this..
I think this is not fare to talk about anyone

Comment: It should be well known that gheeba (backbiting) is a sin.

Comment: But Employees said this is our duty to tell the personal things to our boss,
I Think Peoples do it just for taking appreciation from a boss or another high level officer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wa 3laykum As Salaam,

Joking around that doesn't cause one emotion/physical harm is allowed. Also not to lie when joking.

Regarding a narration it was said:

Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:
The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "He who believes in Allah (Glory Be to HIM) and the Last Day must either speak good or remain silent."

Sahih Muslim

Regarding back biting:

Abu Hurairah said:
The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) was asked: Messenger of ALLAH (Glory Be To HIM) What is back-biting? He replied: It is saying something about your brother which he would dislike. He was asked again: Tell me how the matter stands if what I say about my brother is true? He replied: If what you say of him is true, you have slandered him, and if what you say of him is not true, you have reviled him.

Abu Dawud

ALLAH (Glory Be To HIM) Knows Best

Comment: Thanks. and good spirit

Comment: JazakaALLAH Khairan.